# Insert into c помощью планировщика задач msql

Tags: php, sql, запрос

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь создать планировщик задач для добавления товарных позиций на сайт. К сожалению, он не работает пишет: A comma or a closed braket was expected. Прошу помочь объяснить что я делаю не так:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT timeIN ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
COMMENT 'Внесение новых товаров акционными.'
DO BEGIN
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (1233, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 1233)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (1835, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 1835)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2414, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2414)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2980, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2980)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2981, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2981)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2982, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2982)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2983, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2983)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2984, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2984)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2985, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2985)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2986, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2986)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (2987, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 2987)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3507, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3507)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3508, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3508)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3509, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3509)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3510, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3510)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3511, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3511)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3511, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3511)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3512, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3512)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3843, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3843)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3845, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3845)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3847, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3847)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3848, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3848)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3849, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3849)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3850, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3850)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3851, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3851)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3852, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3852)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3853, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3853)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3854, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3854)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (3855, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 3855)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4217, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4217)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4218, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4218)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4219, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4219)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4220, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4220)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4220, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4220)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4429, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4429)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4443, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4443)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4444, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4444)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4445, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4445)*0.95));
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`, `customer_group_id`, `price`) VALUES (4446, 1, ((SELECT dmx_product.price FROM dmx_product WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 4446)*0.95));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`,`customer_group_id`,`price`) 
VALUES (
            1233, 
            1, 
            (
                (    SELECT dmx_product.price 
                     FROM dmx_product 
                     WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 1233
                )*0.95 -- ??????????
            )
      );


INSERT INTO `dmx_product_special`(`product_id`,`customer_group_id`,`price`) 
VALUES (
            1233, 
            1, 
            (    SELECT dmx_product.price*0.95 -- !!!!!!!!!
                 FROM dmx_product 
                 WHERE dmx_product.product_id = 1233
            )
      );
```

Comment: мб еще итерацию c `insert into .. select ... join ... where d in` ? :)

Comment: @teran Само собой... но автора интересует не оптимизация, а только источник ошибки.

Comment: в mssql такой синтаксис кстати ошибок не дает никаких, странно что оно есть в mysql

Comment: *в mssql такой синтаксис кстати ошибок не дает никаких* Крайне странно... ибо с формальной точки зрения подзапрос возвращает набор записей. Как его можно на что-то умножить - для меня загадка. Видимо, поле dmx_product.product_id уникальное, и сервер "проявляет интеллект" (lamer friendly нынче, к сожалению, общая тенденция)...

Comment: мб потому что я проверял на `select 1` :)

Comment: @teran А проверь на `SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE id=1` - теоретически тебя должны послать ещё на этапе парсинга...

Comment: ругается только на этапе выполнения, если возвращается более одной строки.